# How to convert windows form to an executable file

Tags: c#, forms, file, window, executable

I have a c# windows form program that i want to change to an executable file so i can run it on my computer homescreen without having to open up visual studios. Anyone knows how i can do that? Thanks

Comment: Look at Visual Studio menu Build -> Build Solution / Project name... and search it in the BIN\DEBUG or BIN\RELEASE folder under your project folder.

Comment: Do you mean .exe file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you already debugged your C# windows Form Program, then there's already an executable file for you.  Look in your bin folder.  You might need some of the DLL's that are in there, too.  You can run your program simply by double-clicking on the exe file.

You can also select to make a RELEASE build, then just use that one, instead.

Comment: Thanks guy i found the file alr

Comment: @Lim Jun Wei - Great, glad I could help.  Please close this question by selecting an answer.